# How to correctly use dnsmasq with apache?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, dnsmasq

So I've configured my dnsmasq+hostapd and everything works pretty nice.
And I also started apache with two virtual hosts on 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2.
My goal is to redirect users from one site to my apache host1 and from another site to apache host2. I've tried

```
address=/site.com/127.0.0.1
address=/site2.com/127.0.0.2
```

But it looks like client tries to load its own 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2.
Am I even able to configure dnsmasq with apache to do such redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of googling I'm able to answer my own question. I've just added virtual interface wlan1mon:0 and configured its ip and mask like `10.0.0.2/24`. Now everything works fine for me.